# What does it mean for a matrix to be orthogonally diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm a little confused as to when a matrix is orthogonally diagonalizable.

I understand that if symmetric, it's always orthogonally diagonalizable, but in what other cases can you orthogonally diagonalize a matrix?

Comment: Do you mean orthogonal **and** diagonalizable?

Comment: If by orthogonally diagonalizable you mean, within $M_n(\mathbb{R})$, a matrix of the form $P^TDP$ with $D$ diagonal and $P$ orthogonal, then this is equivalent to symmetric.

Comment: Not an answer, but I hate the term "orthogonally diagonalizable." What an ugly word.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I assume that by $A$ being orthogonally diagonalizable, you mean that there's an *orthogonal* matrix U and a diagonal matrix $D$ such that

$$A = UDU^{-1} = UDU^T.$$

A must then be symmetric, since (note that since $D$ is diagonal, $D^T = D$!)
$$A^T = \left(UDU^T\right)^T = \left(DU^T\right)^TU^T = UD^TU^T = UDU^T = A \text{.}$$

Comment: How can you find `U` and `D`?

Comment: @user83039 The columns of $U$ are the (column) eigenvectors of $A$.

Answer (score 7):

A square matrix is said to be *orthogonally diagonalizable* if there exist an orhtogonal matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP$ is a diagonal matrix.

A square  matrix $A$ is orthogonally diagonalizable $\Leftrightarrow$ $A$ is symmetric.

Answer (score 2):

1. For a complex inner product space, a matrix $A$ is orthogonally diagonalizable iff $A A^* = A^* A$.
2. For a real inner product space, a matrix $A$ is orthogonally diagonalizable iff $A^T = A$.

Notice that the condition in (2) is more strict than (1) in that (2) $\implies$ (1).

Orthogonal diagonalizability of matrix $A \in \mathbb{F}^{n \times n}$ means there exists an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{F}^n$ consisting of eigenvectors of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://www.math.wustl.edu/%7Efreiwald/309orthogdiag.pdf):

> An $n \times n$ matrix is called orthogonally diagonalizable if there is an **orthogonal**
> matrix $U$ and a diagonal matrix $D$ for which  $A = UDU^{-1} = UDU^\top.$
> Thus, an orthogonally diagonalizable matrix is a special kind of diagonalizable matrix: not only
> can we factor $A=PDP^{-1},$ but we can find an matrix that $U=P$ that works. In that case
> case, the columns of $U$ form an basis for $\mathbb R^n.$

Hence, it adds the word "orthogonal" to $P:$ the eigen decomposition of a square matrix $A$ allows $A=PDP^{-1},$ with $P$ containing eigenvectors and $D$ eigenvalues - a square matrix is [similar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity) to a diagonal matrix. But what does 'orthogonal' add to $P$?

Having been shown on other answers that $A$ must be symmetric, I want to add the following intuitive way of thinking of it:

A square matrix $A$ is orthogonally diagonalizable if its eigenvectors are orthogonal *which is the case for any symmetrical matrix). The eigenvalues dilate the space subtended along an orthogonal grid.