# Eigenvalues and eigenvectors in a symmetric matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

> $A$ is a 3x3 symmetric matrix. You know that $2$ and $5$ are eigenvalues of $A$,
>   and
>
> $$V_5 = Span \left( \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} ,\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}  \right) $$
>
> is the eigenspace of the eigenvalue $5$. Which of the following
>   statements is true?
>
> ---
>
> **(1)** $$V_2 = Span \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ -1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix} $$
>
> ---
>
> **(2)** $A$ is diagonalizable.
>
> ---
>
> **(3)** There aren't three eigenvectors of $A$ orthogonal between them.
>
> ---
>
> **(4)** $$ V_2 = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix} | x + y + z = 0 \right\} $$

How can I find the true statement(s)?

Comment: What is your attempt?

Comment: @iamvegan When I posted the question I really didn't know ho to continue. Now, thanks to [Li Chun Min](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1913025/306889) I've provided [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1914023/306889), but I don't know if it is right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You know that $A$ is a square symmetric matrix. So, from the [*Spectral Theorem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem):

> $A$ is [symmetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_matrix) $\iff$ $A$ is [orthogonally diagonalizable](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/392997/306889)

From that you have the following:

> $A$ is symmetric $\implies$ the eigenspaces of $A$ are pairwise
>   orthogonal

This means that $V_\alpha \bot V_\beta$ for every autovalue $\alpha \neq \beta$.

---

From the previous you know that ***option (3)* is false**.

---

You can find the cartesian equation of $V_5$:

$$2x - y - z = 0$$

and the parametric equation of $V_{2_1}$:

$$
\begin{cases}
x = 2 \alpha \\
y = -\alpha \\
z = -\alpha
\end{cases}
$$

So:

$$n[V_5] = d[V_{2_1}] = \begin{pmatrix}2 \\ -1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}$$

This means that $V_{2_1} \bot V_5$, so ***option (1)* is true**.

---

***Option (4)* is false** because:

$$n[V_5] = \begin{pmatrix}2 \\ -1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix} \neq d[V_{2_4}] = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

---

***Option (2)*** is true because: $A$ is symmetric $\implies$ $A$ is diagonalizable

Comment: If $A$ is symmetric then diagonalizable. So $\mathbf{(2)}$ is also true. Your work seems to be okay.

Answer (score 2):

You may use the fact that a matrix is orthogonally diagonalizable iff it is symmetric. You may prove this fact if you are interested. Now you can immediately know whether statements 2 and 3 are true or not. Then what remains is to find a basis (consists of 1 vector $\vec v$ only) for $V_2$. (Hint: you know that $\vec v$ is orthogonal to $V_5$.)

Comment: Thanks for your help: from your answer I've understand how to start. I've write [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1914023/306889), but I really don't know if it's right.