# Is every symmetric matrix in $\mathbb R^n$ a (non-uniform) stretch?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, intuition, svd, transpose

I conjecture that in $\mathbb R^n$, every symmetric matrix is a *non-uniform stretch*.  Am I correct?

By *non-uniform stretch*, I mean that if $T$ is a non-uniform stretch, there exists an orthonormal basis $\{t_n\}$ of $\mathbb R^n$ such that for all $x, T(x) \cdot t_i = \lambda_i x \cdot t_i$.  This includes collapse ($\lambda_i = 0$) and reflection ($\lambda_i < 0$).

Support for conjecture: First, consider symmetric matrices of the form $A^\top A$.  These decompose into $A = U \Sigma V ^ \top$ and $A^\top = V \Sigma ^\top U^\top$, so $A ^ \top A = U \Sigma V ^ \top V \Sigma ^\top \Sigma U = U \Sigma ^2 U^{-1}$.  Since $U$ is orthogonal, it is a rotation, and so we have a rotation, a non-uniform stretch along the standard basis, and rotation back, resulting in a non-uniform stretch along an arbitrary orthonormal basis.  Is that correct?

What about symmetric matrices that [cannot be expressed in $\mathbb R^n$ as $A^\top A$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3125579/can-any-symmetrix-matrix-be-written-as-ata)? What geometric form can they take?

*Note: [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1413763/the-intution-behind-real-symmetric-matrices-and-their-real-eigenvectors) provides relevant background but does not directly address this question.*

---

### Update

Based on comments below, an alternate way of phrasing this question may be: Prove that the set of orthorgonally diagonizable matrices in $\mathbb R^n$ is precisely the set of non-uniform stretches in $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Your "non-uniform stretch" is better known as "orthogonally diagonalizable (over $\mathbb{R}$)". You are saying that a symmetric matrix is always orthogonally diagonalizable over $\mathbb{R}$; this is already addressed in the post you link to. In fact, the two conditions are equivalent: an $n\times n$ matrix with real coefficients is orthogonally diagonalizable if and only if it is symmetric.  Now, a symmetric matrix $S$ is expressible as $A^TA$ for some $A$ if and only if it is positive semidefinite, if and only if all its eigenvalues are nonnegative.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks! I'm looking up "orthogonally diagonalizable (over $\mathbb R$)" but can find no proof that it is the same as what I termed a non-uniform stretch.  In fact, the only definition I can find of it is the decomposition which I used, which would bring to circular reasoning; see, e.g. ["What does it mean for a matrix to be orthogonally diagonalizable?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/392983/what-does-it-mean-for-a-matrix-to-be-orthogonally-diagonalizable).  Can you direct me to some relevant background?

Comment: "Orthogonally diagonalizable" means "there exists an orthonormal basis consisting of eigenvectors". Your equation $T(x)\cdot t_1 = \lambda_ix$ makes no sense as written ($x$ would have to be an element of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and then $T(x)\cdot t_i$ would be a scalar, but then $\lambda_i x$ would be a vector set equal to a scalar). So I assumed that you meant $T(t_i) = \lambda_i t_i$. If that is not what you meant, then you need to change that "definition", because right now it's nonsense.

Comment: By the way, orthogonal does not imply rotation in $\mathbb{R}^n$, not even in $\mathbb{R}^2$. A reflection about a line through the origin is orthogonal, but not a rotation.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Definition corrected - I had inadvertently omitted the final dot product.  And I've updated the question / conjecture based on your comments.  Can you take a look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: what you call a "non-uniform stretch" is what is usually called "orthogonally diagonalizable."

Recall that if $A$ is a square matrix, then an eigenvector of $A$ is a nonzero vector $\mathbf{x}$ such that there exists a scalar $\lambda$ with $A\mathbf{x}=\lambda\mathbf{x}$. An $n\times n$ matrix is *diagonalizable* if and only if there exists a basis $\mathbf{v}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{v}_n$ such that each $\mathbf{v}_i$ is an eigenvector of $A$; and is **orthogonally diagonalizable** if there exists an *orthonormal* basis $\mathbf{v}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{v}_n$ such that each $\mathbf{v}_i$ is an eigenvector of $A$.

Moreover, if $[\mathbf{v}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{v}_n]$ is an orthonormal basis, then it is well known that for every vector $\mathbf{x}$ we have
$$\mathbf{x} = (\mathbf{x}\cdot \mathbf{v}_1)\mathbf{v}_1 + \cdots + (\mathbf{x}\cdot \mathbf{v}_n)\mathbf{v}_n,$$
where $\cdot$ is the standard inner product (you can replace the dot product with an arbitrary inner product $\langle -,-\rangle$).

You are requiring that $A\mathbf{x}\cdot t_i = \lambda_i\mathbf{x}\cdot t_i$. Putting $\mathbf{x}=t_j$ we obtain
$$\begin{align*}
At_j &= \sum_{i=1}^n (At_j\cdot t_i)t_i\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n (\lambda_i t_i\cdot t_j)t_i\\
&= \lambda_jt_j,
\end{align*}$$
so each $t_i$ is an eigenvector of $A$. Conversely, if each $t_i$ is an eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda_i$, then we have for every vector $\mathbf{x}$,
$$\begin{align*}
A\mathbf{x}\cdot t_j &= \left( A\left(\sum_{i=1}^n (\mathbf{x}\cdot t_i)t_i\right)\right)\cdot t_j\\
&= \left( \sum_{i=1}^n A(\mathbf{x}\cdot t_i)t_i\right)\cdot t_j\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n (\mathbf{x}\cdot t_i)(At_i\cdot t_j)\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n (\mathbf{x}\cdot t_i) (\lambda_i t_i\cdot t_j)\\
&= (\mathbf{x}\cdot t_i)\lambda_i\\
&= \lambda_i \mathbf{x}\cdot t_i,
\end{align*}$$
satisfying your requirements.

So your question really amounts to:

> Is every symmetric matrix orthogonally diagonalizable (over $\mathbb{R}$)?

The "over $\mathbb{R}$" clause is to ensure that all $\lambda_i$ are real numbers, and all vectors have real coordinates. It is "easier" to orthogonally diagonalize a matrix over $\mathbb{C}$ (a matrix $A$ with complex coefficients is orthogonally diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$ if and only if $AA^*=A^*A$, where $A^*$ is the conjugate transpose), than over $\mathbb{R}$.

The answer is "yes", as is classically known:

> **Theorem.** An $n\times n$ matrix with real coefficient is orthogonally diagonalizable if and only if $A$ is symmetric.

We need some lemmas.

**Lemma.** Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix with real coefficients. Then the unique $n\times n$ matrix such that for all vectors $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $(A\mathbf{x}) \cdot y = \mathbf{x}\cdot(B\mathbf{y})$ is $B=A^T$, the transpose of $A$.

*Proof.* Writing vectors as columns, we have that $\mathbf{x}\cdot\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{y}^T\mathbf{x}$ (matrix product, interpreting a $1\times 1$ matrix as a scalar).

Thus, we have
$$(A\mathbf{x})\cdot \mathbf{y} = \mathbf{y}^T(A\mathbf{x}) = (\mathbf{y}^TA)\mathbf{x} = (A^T\mathbf{y})^T\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{x}\cdot(A^T\mathbf{y}).$$
So $A^T$ satisfies the equation. Conversely, if $B$ also satisfies the equation, then for all $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ we have
$$\mathbf{x}\cdot(A^T\mathbf{y}) - \mathbf{x}\cdot(B\mathbf{y}) = \mathbf{x}\cdot(A^T-B)\mathbf{y} = 0,$$
so $(A^T-B)\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{0}$ for all $\mathbf{y}$, hence $A^T=B$. $\Box$

Over $\mathbb{C}$, the inner product is given by $\mathbf{y}^*\mathbf{x}$, where $A^*$ is the conjugate tranpose of the matrix $A$, and the unique matrix $B$ such that $A\mathbf{x}\cdot\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{x}\cdot B\mathbf{y}$ is $B=A^*$.

**Lemma 2.** Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix with complex coefficients such that $AA^*=A^*A$. If $\mathbf{x}$ is an eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to $\lambda$, then $\mathbf{x}$ is an eigenvector of $A^*$ corresponding to $\overline{\lambda}$.  In particular, if $A=A^*$, then $\lambda$ is a real number.

*Proof.* Note that
$$\lVert A\mathbf{x}\rVert^2 = (A\mathbf{x})\cdot(A\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{x}\cdot (A^*A)\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{x}\cdot (AA^*)\mathbf{x} = (A^*\mathbf{x})\cdot(A^*\mathbf{x}) = \lVert A^*\mathbf{x}\rVert^2.$$

Since $(A-\lambda I)$ commutes with $A^*-\overline{\lambda}I - (A-\lambda I)^*$ when $A$ commutes with $A^*$, we have
$$0 = \lVert (A-\lambda I)\mathbf{x}\rVert^2 = \lVert (A^*-\overline{\lambda}I)\mathbf{x}\rVert^2.$$
So $A^*\mathbf{x}=\overline{\lambda}\mathbf{x}$. When $A=A^*$, we conclude that $\mathbf{x}$ is an eigenvector of both $\lambda$ and $\overline{\lambda}$, so $\lambda=\overline{\lambda}$ is a real number. $\Box$

Note that the characteristic polynomial of a symmetric matrix with real coefficients must therefore split over $\mathbb{R}$: for it splits over $\mathbb{C}$ and its roots are the eigenvalues of $A$, but by Lemma 2 those eigenvalues are real numbers.

Now we can apply Schur's Lemma:

**Schur's Lemma.** Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ real matrix whose characteristic polynomial splits. Then there is an orthonormal basis $\beta$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that the coordinate matrix $[L_A]_{\beta}$ of multiplication by $A$ relative to the basis $\beta$ is upper triangular.

*Proof.* Because the characteristic polynomial splits, we know there is a basis $\gamma=[\mathbf{v}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{v}_n]$ such that $[L_A]_{\gamma}$ is upper triangular (e.g., a Jordan Canonical basis); that is $A\mathbf{v}_i\in\mathrm{span}(\mathbf{v}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{v}_i)$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$.

We apply Gram-Schmidt to the basis $\gamma=[\mathbf{v}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{v}_n]$ to obtain an orthonormal basis $\beta=[\mathbf{u}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{u}_n]$, such that $\mathrm{span}(\mathbf{v}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{v}_i) = \mathrm{span}(\mathbf{u}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{u}_i)$ for each $i$. It follows that $[L_A]_{\beta}$ is upper triangular, as desired. $\Box$

**Theorem** (sometimes called the Spectral Theorem). Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix with real coefficients. Then $A$ is orthogonally diagonalizable over $\mathbb{R}$ if and only if $A$ is symmetric.

*Proof.* Assume first that $A$ is orthogonally diagonalizable, and let $[\mathbf{v}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{v}_n]$ be an orthonormal basis consisting of eigenvectors of $A$ corresponding to the real numbers $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$. Let $D$ be the diagonal matrix with entries $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$, and let $V$ be the matrix whose columns are the vectors $\mathbf{v}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{v}_n$. Then we have that
$V^{-1}AV = D$, or equivalently (since the columns of $V$ are orthonormal) that
$$A = VDV^T.$$
We prove that $A$ is symmetric. The $(i,k)$ entry of $VD$ is $\lambda_kv_{ik}$, where $v_{ik}$ is the $(i,k)$ entry of $V$, and $v_{kj}^T$ the $(k,j)$ entry of $V^T$ (which equals $v_{jk}$). So the $(i,j)$ entry of $A$ is
$$a_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_kv_{ik}v_{kj}^T = \sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_kv_{ik}v_{jk}.$$
On the other hand, the $(j,i)$ entry is
$$a_{ji}=\sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_kv_{jk}v_{ki}^T = \sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_k v_{jk}v_{ik} = a_{ij}.$$
So $A$ is symmetric.

Conversely, assume that $A$ is symmetric. Then its characteristic polynomia splits, so there is an orthonormal basis $\beta=[\mathbf{v}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{v}_n]$ such that $A\mathbf{v}_i\in\mathrm{span}(\mathbf{v}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{v}_i)$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$.

Let $V$ be the matrix whose columns are the vectors in $\beta$. Then $A=VUV^T$, where $U$ is an upper triangular matrix. Then
$$A = A^T = (VUV^T)^T = VU^TV^T.$$
But that means that $VUV^T = VU^TV^T$; since $V$ is invertible, it follows that $U=U^T$. But $U$ is upper triangular, and $U^T$ is lower triangular. Therefore, $U$ is actually *diagonal*, so that each of $\mathbf{v}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{v}_n$ is an eigenvector of $A$. Thus, there is an orthonormal basis consisting of eigenvectors of $A$, as desired. $\Box$

Comment: This is a fantastic answer and incredibly clear.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, note that the spectral theorem states that the orthogonally diagonalizable matrices are precisely the symmetric matrices.

In order to see that the non-uniform stretches in $\Bbb R^n$ are the same as the orthogonally diagonalizable matrices, note that $T(x)$ can be expressed as
$$
T(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i (x \cdot t_i)t_i = \left[\sum_{i=1}^n  \lambda_i t_it_i^\top \right]x = [QDQ^T]x,
$$
where $Q$ denotes the orthogonal matrix whose columns are $t_1,\dots,t_n$ and $D$ denotes the diagonal matrix whose diagonal entries are $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n$.

Comment: Does the above require using complex numbers? If so, does it apply to the OP statement of "in $\mathbb R^n$"?

Comment: No it does not, I’m not sure what gave you that impression

Comment: Thanks.  Nothing gave me that impression, I just wanted to clarify - this is new material for me.